# Action happening for all the items in v-for but I want to run the action on just the item I clicked on

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I have an icon in the `v-for` loop and I want the action to be performed specifically to the one icon but it is happening for all the icons that are repeating because of `v-for`.

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <tr
      v-for="(randomData, randomIndex) in obj['randomData']"
      :key="randomIndex"
      class="random-table"
    >
      <td data-label="Activity Alert">
        <el-popover
          v-model="remindMeVisibility"
          placement="left-start"
          width="500"
          trigger="manual"
          class="popover-form"
        >
          <RemindMe />
          <i
            slot="reference"
            class="el-icon-message-solid reminder-icon"
            @click="remindMeVisibility = true"
          ></i>
        </el-popover>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      remindMeVisibility: false,
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

Comment: What is your action supposed to do here? Change something regarding a specific element in your `v-for`? You could use the `index` in `(item, index) in items` and apply a specific method to that specific index.

Comment: @kissu Whenever I click on the icon it sets the v-model value to true. But the v-model value is common to all the indexes here and instead of showing one dialog next to a specific reminder icon, it shows in front of all.

Comment: Where is `remindMeVisibility` defined? Could you please show more of the code? `v-for` + relevant `script` part? Or just provide a [repro].

Comment: @kissu Edited the post. I hope it makes sense. Although I'm using this element UI popover. When v-model is true it shows the form next to the icon.

Comment: You should probably not call it `randomData` when iterating on it, since it's being used to access a field on your `obj`. Rather use something like `v-for="(item, index) in obj['randomData']"`. Also, `remindMeVisibility` is unique here. We probably want something on your `obj`, with a `remindMeVisibility` on each `item`. What is the content of `obj.randomData` here?

Comment: @kissu `obj.randomData` contains key-value pair. And I guess the v-model will accept true or false as shown in the documentation of elementUI. So, I don't think passing something unique might help.

Comment: `v-model` is bound to? `remindMeVisibility`, as single state, not tied to any element list. [`v-model`](https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/popover#attributes) in the documentation is targeting a single element. If you want to have it linked to a list of element and toggling each one of them independently, you will need to link that one to a specific key of each element of your list. Hence why I'm (still) asking for the full code used here: key-pair combo is the thing that we need to target here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working example on how to have a specific popover edit per element for a given list.

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <pre>{{ cityNames }}</pre>

    <section>
      <div v-for="city in cityNames" :key="city.id">
        <span>City {{ city.name }}</span>
        <el-popover v-model="city.popoverOpen" placement="top" width="160" class="popover">
          <el-button slot="reference">Update visibility</el-button>
          <p>Change the visibility of the City?</p>
          <div style="text-align: right; margin: 0">
            <el-button size="mini" type="text" @click="toggleCityVisibility({ id: city.id, visibility: false })">
              Hide it
            </el-button>
            <el-button type="primary" size="mini" @click="toggleCityVisibility({ id: city.id, visibility: true })">
              Make visible
            </el-button>
          </div>
        </el-popover>
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      cityNames: [
        {
          id: 1,
          name: 'beijing',
          remindMeVisibility: false,
          popoverOpen: false,
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          name: 'shanghai',
          remindMeVisibility: false,
          popoverOpen: false,
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          name: 'guangzhou',
          remindMeVisibility: false,
          popoverOpen: false,
        }
      ]
    };
  },
  methods: {
    toggleCityVisibility({ id, visibility }) {
      console.log('id', id, 'visibility', visibility)
      this.targetedCity = this.cityNames.find(city => city.id === id)
      this.targetedCity.remindMeVisibility = visibility
    }
  },
}
</script>

<style scoped>
.popover {
  margin-left: 1rem;
}
</style>
```

Here, we do have a list of cities, and we want to toggle their visibility (`remindMeVisibility`).
The `id` in the list was given for the `:key` uniqueness + find it later on when editing the visibility of it.
I didn't expected `popoverOpen` to be required here, but it is (a global popover state is not feasible from what I've tried).

This is how it looks

[image]